# update data from MYSQL to CH Cluster problem

Tags: clickhouse

This problem makes me very confused.

I use ReplicatedMergeTree to create the table.
Here is update SQL:

[image]

When I first run it the result is correct, but run it again and it will be zero.

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you add the sql-queries & result as text not images? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mutations are asynchronous. Your delete was sent to Zookeeper, then your insert ran, then your select and likely then your delete statement. If you are updating from mysql you should look at bin log replication to replicate only new or changed data over. Clickhouse works best with new data, not updates/deletes as those are asynchronous.

`A mutation query returns immediately after the mutation entry is added (in case of replicated tables to ZooKeeper, for non-replicated tables - to the filesystem). The mutation itself executes asynchronously using the system profile settings. To track the progress of mutations you can use the system.mutations table. A mutation that was successfully submitted will continue to execute even if ClickHouse servers are restarted. There is no way to roll back the mutation once it is submitted, but if the mutation is stuck for some reason it can be cancelled with the KILL MUTATION query.`

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/#mutations

Answer (score 0):

did you try to run

```
SELECT count(*) FROM ods.fb_daily_inventory WHERE uds_load_date >= '2021-05-04'
```

on MySQL server, to ensure data still exists on MySQL?